# Is it possible to modify XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open()?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to inject callbacks into `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open()` so I can know the method and the url, as well as setting a timestamp for the performance report (alone with the modified `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send()`).

Here is what I came up so far:

```
function addXMLRequestCallback(open, callback) {
    var nativeOpen, nativeSend, i;
    if (XMLHttpRequest.callbacks) {
        XMLHttpRequest.callbacks.push(callback);
    } else {
        XMLHttpRequest.callbacks = [callback];
        nativeOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
            open.forEach(function(item) {
                // not sure what to do here...
            });
        }
        nativeSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
            for (i = 0; i < XMLHttpRequest.callbacks.length; i++) {
                XMLHttpRequest.callbacks[i](this);
            }
            nativeSend.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
}
addXMLRequestCallback(function(method,url){
    // Maybe instead I should put code here...
}, function(xhr) {
    // then do something here?
});
```

Comment: Well just do it the same way you did with `send`. We don't know what to do there either, what do *you want* `open.forEach` to do?

Answer (score 1):

What you had with the `send` method was the right approach. In the following snippet, I only inplemented a listener that gets called whenever an `XMLHttpRequest`'s `open` method is called. I'm sure you can implement the same for `send`.

```js
(function () {
  var nativeOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
  var callbacks = XMLHttpRequest.callbacks = [];
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function () {
    callbacks.forEach(callback => callback.apply(this, arguments));
    nativeOpen.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})();

function addXHROpenCallback (cb) {
  XMLHttpRequest.callbacks.push(cb);
}

addXHROpenCallback(function (method, url) {
  console.log(`XHR opened. Method: ${method}, URL: ${url}`);
});

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com');
```

However, ask yourself if you really need to modify a built-in prototype. Consider creating a wrapper class that does the same, but without modifying a prototype.

Comment: I will give it a try tmr. Thanks.